# Values removed on click on a button

Tags: javascript, click, listener

I have the following code :

`var valid = document.getElementById('valid');`

`console.log(indexTab);`

`valid.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {`
    `console.log(indexTab);`
    `updateArtifact(artifact);`
    `modal.style.display = "none";
});`

When I click on the button which id is 'valid', indexTab doesn't have the same value as before.
The previous values for indexTab were :

`1225: "text1"
1226: "text2"
1227: ["921"]
1228: ["36"]`

and after it is :

`1225: "text1"
1226: "text2"
1227: [null]
1228: [null]`

Is there anything that I'm missing that may cause this issue ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: We need to know what happens in updateArtifact I guess..

Comment: 1. What is `indexTab` (e.g object, number value etc). 2. What does the ? `updateArtifact(...)` function do?

Comment: Your code and output is not showing any correspondence, Please share the complete code. What does `updateArtifact(artifact)` do? What are `indexTab` and `artifact`?

Comment: Update artifact is a big function that only reads indexTab but a console.log inside this function is shown after so the value is already changed at this point.

indexTab is an object with key => value where the value is either a string (and in this case, there is no value removed) or an array of values (with are removed as I said).